# HTML CSS Tab Controls - Multiple tab controls on the same page

Tags: html, css, tabs

I grabbed a simple tab control from the css tricks site and its working great for me, except when I have two tab controls on the same page, clicking the bottom control simply changes the tab page of the top control.

The CSS Tricks page with the original code [is here](https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/)

Changing the name= attribute for the second group doesn't fix it.

Renaming the id's of each tab in the second group also doesn't fit it.

Is there a way to have two independently operating tabs on the same page ?

FWIW the HTML and CSS are fairly simple:

```css
        .tabs {
          position: relative;   
          min-height: 100px;    
          clear: both;
          margin: 25px 0;
        }
        .tabs .tab {
          float: left;
        }
        .tabs .tab label {
          background: #eee; 
          padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; 
          border: 1px solid #ccc; 
          position: relative;
          left: 1px; 
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .tabs .tab [type=radio] {
          display: none;   
        }
        .tabs .content {
          position: absolute;
          top: 18px;
          left: 0;
          background: white;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          padding: 20px;
          border: 1px solid #ccc; 
          overflow:auto;
        }
        .tabs [type=radio]:checked ~ label {
          background: white;
          border-bottom: 1px solid white;
          z-index: 2;
        }
        .tabs [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
          z-index: 1;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="tabs">
        
       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
           <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
           
           <div class="content">
               stuff1
           </div> 
       </div>
        
       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
           
           <div class="content">
               stuff2
           </div> 
       </div>
        
        <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
         
           <div class="content">
               stuff3
           </div> 
       </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="tabs">
        
       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
           <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
           
           <div class="content">
               stuff4
           </div> 
       </div>
        
       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
           
           <div class="content">
               stuff5
           </div> 
       </div>
        
        <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
         
           <div class="content">
               stuff6
           </div> 
       </div>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part to change is the `label` and the `id`:

```
<input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
<label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
```

I've edited your snippet.

```css
        .tabs {
          position: relative;   
          min-height: 100px;    
          clear: both;
          margin: 25px 0;
        }
        .tabs .tab {
          float: left;
        }
        .tabs .tab label {
          background: #eee; 
          padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; 
          border: 1px solid #ccc; 
          position: relative;
          left: 1px; 
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .tabs .tab [type=radio] {
          display: none;   
        }
        .tabs .content {
          position: absolute;
          top: 18px;
          left: 0;
          background: white;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          padding: 20px;
          border: 1px solid #ccc; 
          overflow:auto;
        }
        .tabs [type=radio]:checked ~ label {
          background: white;
          border-bottom: 1px solid white;
          z-index: 2;
        }
        .tabs [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
          z-index: 1;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="tabs">
        
       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
           <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
           
           <div class="content">
               stuff1
           </div> 
       </div>
        
       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
           
           <div class="content">
               stuff2
           </div> 
       </div>
        
        <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
         
           <div class="content">
               stuff3
           </div> 
       </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="tabs">
        
       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-1" checked>
           <label for="tab-4">Tab One</label>
           
           <div class="content">
               stuff4
           </div> 
       </div>
        
       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-5">Tab Two</label>
           
           <div class="content">
               stuff5
           </div> 
       </div>
        
        <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-6" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-6">Tab Three</label>
         
           <div class="content">
               stuff6
           </div> 
       </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Marked as answer, and ego deflated because I didn't spot that myself !! thanks again